# Geometric Mean instead of Simple Mean

Tags: machine-learning, math, statistics

Appreciated if some one can explain me some use cases for geometric mean instead of simple Mean

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use of geometric mean:
A geometric mean is useful in machine learning when comparing items with a different number of properties and numerical ranges. The geometric mean normalizes the number ranges giving each property equal weight in the average. This contrasts with arithmetic mean where a larger number range would more greatly affect the average than a smaller number range. To better understand this try doing a geometric mean calculation compared with an arithmetic mean calculation using two numbers. Make one number be chosen from 0 to 5 and the other number from 0 to 100. Vary the two numbers to see how each affects the average.

Harmonic mean : Harmonic mean is a type of average generally used for numbers that represent a rate or ratio such as the precision and the recall in information retrieval. The harmonic mean can be described as the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of the reciprocals of the data.

Use of Harmonic mean:
The harmonic mean is used in machine learning to calculate something called an F-score or F-measure. The F-score is a test for evaluating the performance of algorithms in information retrieval.